# how to ignore fetching a child table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i have two tables .   health   &   Network

This is my Health Table Entity:

```
   @Table(name="health")
   public class Health   implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id 
@Column(name="hid")
private int hid;

@Column(name="ivid")
private int ivid;

@JoinColumn(name = "nwid")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Networks nwid;
```

}

I am trying to fetch a Health row against which there is nothing available in Network Table and thats why its not giving me that rows record of health table..

Where as i want that row from health and i dont want it to look into the network table for that record..

If i dont use crit.createAlias... server call get failed.

```
            try
      {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Health.class);
        crit.createAlias("nwid", "network");
        crit.createAlias("network.statsId", "stats");
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("ivid", 0));   
        Iterator<Health> it = crit.list().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
        health  = it.next();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
crit.createAlias("nwid", "network");
```

to

```
crit.createAlias("nwid", "network", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Comment: Also try to add to @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, nullable = true) and left_join to network.statsId

Comment: leftJoin on stats is now giving me one record , in which network is null .. and when the data moves from server to client it fails .. i am trying to put nullable = true , but it says The attribute nullable is undefined for the annotation type ManyToOn

Comment: Sorry, nullable should be in @JoinColumn

Comment: thanks, but still the same error , it getting the row with null network and null stats .. I put nullable = true on both .. It runs fine if i try to fetch some other record from health which is present in Network

Comment: Yes, null if not exists, so what do you want to get?

Comment: i just want to get the Health table values .... I am ok with this NULL.. but it makes the call failed

Comment: can i just ignore one column at run time .. So i do not have this nwid column in my returning result

Comment: [WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: This is different issue, make sure that you have @Transactional for your method if you use annotations.

Comment: Transactional will ignore the entity columns with the db , But in some other method i DONT want to ignore this

Comment: Ok, in this method after this LeftJoin .. i am just creating a new HealthEntity instance and assigning it to nwid , which is now making call server call success